# ¿Por qué no puedo usar herencia múltiple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, herencia

Estoy aprendiendo Python espero sean flexibles. Quiero comprobar si me funciono o no la herencia múltiple por lo que pretendo que esta clase `dog`:

```
class dog(animal,to_jump):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    print(f"my dog {self.name} is barking and he is {self.var}")
```

tambien herede el método de esta:

```
class to_jump:
    #this is a method
    def jump(self):
        self.var = "jumping"
```

para comprobarlo quiero imprimir lo que esta en la variable de la clase `to_jump (self.var)`
pero en otra clase, quiero que haga esta impresión correctamente.

```
print(f"my dog {self.name} is barking and he is {self.var}")
```

y me lanza este error.

> ```
> File "herencia.py", line 18, in __init__
>     print(f"my dog {self.name} is barking and he is {self.var}"
> AttributeError: 'dog' object has no attribute 'var'
> ```

esta es la instancia de la clase dog.

```
instancia = dog("bruno")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es un problema de herencia, es un problema de dónde creas el atributo de instancia. `self.var` se crea en `jump`, **no existe antes de que `jump` sea llamado**, ni en la clase padre ni en `Dog`.

> ```
> >>> inst = to_jump()
> >>> inst.var
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "main", line 1, in <module>
>     inst.var
>
> AttributeError: 'to_jump' object has no attribute 'var'
>
> >>> inst.jump()
> >>> inst.var
> 'jumping'
> ```

Si en el inicializador llamas al método heredado `jump` antes de intentar usar el atributo de instancia, no hay problema alguno:

```
class Animal:
    pass

class Saltarin:
    def jump(self):
        self.var = "jumping"

class Dog(Animal, Saltarin):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.jump()
        print(f"my dog {self.name} is barking and he is {self.var}")


instancia = Dog("bruno")
```

Esta es una de las razones por las que siempre es buena practica inicializar todo atributo de instancia en el inicializador de la clase:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vive = True
        super().__init__()

class Saltarin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.estado = "corriendo"
        super().__init__()

    def saltar(self):
        self.estado = "saltando"

class Perro(Animal, Saltarin):
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        super().__init__()
        self.nombre = nombre
        print(f"Mi pero {self.nombre} está ladrando y está {self.estado}")
        self.saltar()
        print(f"Mi pero {self.nombre} está ladrando y está {self.estado}")


instancia = Perro("Bruno")
```

> ```
> Mi pero Bruno está ladrando y está corriendo
> Mi pero Bruno está ladrando y está saltando
> ```

Comment: muchas gracias. ademas agradezco por sus editaciones estoy aprendiendo de este foro

Comment: @mauricio recuerda marcar como aceptada esta respuesta si resolvió tu problema o duda.

Comment: ok. lo hago gracias